# centos 6 with webmin and virtualmin can't run php

Tags: linux, php, centos

i can't run php on centos 6 with webmin and virtualmin (fresh install)

```
<? echo phpinfo ?>
```

when run above php code, it is blank, but right click source code, i can see the php code that is "" in plain text....

any ideas?

Comment: What web server, and how is it configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, does that filename end in .php?

If so, can you please run:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

and update with the results?

My initial guess is that PHP isn't installed. Assuming you don't see something like:

```
php-common.i686                    5.3.2-6.el6_0.1                   @updates   
php-mysql.i686                     5.3.2-6.el6_0.1                   @updates   
php-pdo.i686                       5.3.2-6.el6_0.1                   @updates
```

then you need to run

```
sudo yum install php -y
```

which will then install php and the dependencies. At that point, you'll want to restart your web service:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

And try the page again.

If it was already installed and restarting the service didn't help, then we'll have to actually look at the php config section of Apache. But lets verify that this is OK first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (entire contents of the file):

```
<?php phpinfo();
```